# How can I create a device node for a character device driver in Android?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have tried using mknod but it is not defined in Android kernel. Is there any other way using which I could create the device node?

Comment: This is a rooted device, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ueventd.rc` to declare your device entries. This file is read by init. It is a kind of minimal udev.

Comment: Thanks. How does the entry get linked to my device driver? Does the linking happens based on the name given to the character devices?

Comment: after a look over the ueventd source code, the kernel driver must expose its character device via device_create() before udev or ueventd will know it exists